# Why does it say that TabularList is not defined I imported fastai.tabular

Tags: classification, tabular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNk28.png)

I imprted fastai.tabular.all but it still says that TabulaList is not defined

Comment: You should include all code that is relevant to the questions. This way people can really help, try out your code and fix it. In this case, it's important you include you import statement (there are different ways to phrase an import statement and it affects your code that relies on that import)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?